# Can I run pig0.12 with hadoop-2.2.0 distribution?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I installed hadoop-2.2.0 and can run MR jobs. Configured pig0.12 and trying to use the interactie `grunt` shell. But when I try to create data into records from input using

```
records = LOAD '/temp/temp.txt' AS (year:chararray, temperature:int, quality:int);
```

I get the following. Did not see this when I used pig0.12 earlier with hadoop-1.2.1 distribution.

```
2013-11-27 11:11:37,225 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.jobtracker.maxtasks.per.job is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.maxtasks.perjob
2013-11-27 11:11:37,225 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.system.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.system.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,226 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.reduce.max.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.maxattempts
2013-11-27 11:11:37,226 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum
2013-11-27 11:11:37,226 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.local.dir.minspacekill is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.local.dir.minspacekill
2013-11-27 11:11:37,227 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.jobtracker.job.history.block.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.jobhistory.block.size
2013-11-27 11:11:37,227 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.backup.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.backup.address
2013-11-27 11:11:37,227 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.name.edits.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.edits.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,227 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.timeout is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.timeout
2013-11-27 11:11:37,227 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.tracker.task-controller is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.taskcontroller
2013-11-27 11:11:37,228 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.local.dir.minspacestart is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.local.dir.minspacestart
2013-11-27 11:11:37,228 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - jobclient.progress.monitor.poll.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.progressmonitor.pollinterval
2013-11-27 11:11:37,228 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.shuffle.merge.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.merge.percent
2013-11-27 11:11:37,228 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.block.size is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.blocksize
2013-11-27 11:11:37,228 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.df.interval is deprecated. Instead, use fs.df.interval
2013-11-27 11:11:37,229 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.skip.reduce.max.skip.groups is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.skip.maxgroups
2013-11-27 11:11:37,229 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.map.max.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.maxattempts
2013-11-27 11:11:37,229 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.profile is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.profile
2013-11-27 11:11:37,229 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapreduce.job.counters.limit is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.counters.max
2013-11-27 11:11:37,229 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.child.tmp is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.tmp.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,230 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.replication.min is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.min
2013-11-27 11:11:37,230 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.safemode.threshold.pct is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct
2013-11-27 11:11:37,230 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.https.client.keystore.resource is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client.https.keystore.resource
2013-11-27 11:11:37,230 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum
2013-11-27 11:11:37,231 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.userlog.limit.kb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.userlog.limit.kb
2013-11-27 11:11:37,231 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative
2013-11-27 11:11:37,231 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.reduce.parallel.copies is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.parallelcopies
2013-11-27 11:11:37,231 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
2013-11-27 11:11:37,231 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.skip.attempts.to.start.skipping is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.skip.start.attempts
2013-11-27 11:11:37,232 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.min.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
2013-11-27 11:11:37,232 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - jobclient.completion.poll.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.completion.pollinterval
2013-11-27 11:11:37,232 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - jobclient.output.filter is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.output.filter
2013-11-27 11:11:37,232 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.committer.job.setup.cleanup.needed is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.committer.setup.cleanup.needed
2013-11-27 11:11:37,232 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.max.objects is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.max.objects
2013-11-27 11:11:37,233 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address
2013-11-27 11:11:37,233 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress
2013-11-27 11:11:37,233 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.expiry.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.expire.trackers.interval
2013-11-27 11:11:37,233 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.datanode.max.xcievers is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.max.transfer.threads
2013-11-27 11:11:37,233 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.submit.replication is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.client.submit.file.replication
2013-11-27 11:11:37,234 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.taskscheduler
2013-11-27 11:11:37,238 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.temp.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.temp.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,239 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.taskmemorymanager.monitoring-interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.taskmemorymanager.monitoringinterval
2013-11-27 11:11:37,239 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
2013-11-27 11:11:37,239 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compression.codec is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec
2013-11-27 11:11:37,239 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.userlog.retain.hours is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.userlog.retain.hours
2013-11-27 11:11:37,239 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.healthChecker.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.healthchecker.interval
2013-11-27 11:11:37,240 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.retiredjobs.cache.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.retiredjobs.cache.size
2013-11-27 11:11:37,240 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.max.tracker.failures is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maxtaskfailures.per.tracker
2013-11-27 11:11:37,240 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.replication.considerLoad is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.considerLoad
2013-11-27 11:11:37,240 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
2013-11-27 11:11:37,242 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.acls.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.acls.enabled
2013-11-27 11:11:37,242 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps
2013-11-27 11:11:37,242 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.handler.count is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.handler.count
2013-11-27 11:11:37,242 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - job.end.retry.attempts is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.end-notification.retry.attempts
2013-11-27 11:11:37,242 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.http-address
2013-11-27 11:11:37,242 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,246 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.name.dir.restore is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.name.dir.restore
2013-11-27 11:11:37,246 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.https.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.https-address
2013-11-27 11:11:37,247 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.healthChecker.script.timeout is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.healthchecker.script.timeout
2013-11-27 11:11:37,247 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.shuffle.connect.timeout is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.connect.timeout
2013-11-27 11:11:37,247 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.backup.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.backup.http-address
2013-11-27 11:11:37,247 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.secondary.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address
2013-11-27 11:11:37,247 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.umaskmode is deprecated. Instead, use fs.permissions.umask-mode
2013-11-27 11:11:37,248 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.sort.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb
2013-11-27 11:11:37,248 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.replication.interval is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.replication.interval
2013-11-27 11:11:37,248 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.name.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.name.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,248 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.indexcache.mb is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.indexcache.mb
2013-11-27 11:11:37,248 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - keep.failed.task.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.files.preserve.failedtasks
2013-11-27 11:11:37,249 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.heartbeats.in.second is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.heartbeats.in.second
2013-11-27 11:11:37,249 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.permissions is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.permissions.enabled
2013-11-27 11:11:37,249 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.speculative.execution.slowTaskThreshold is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.speculative.slowtaskthreshold
2013-11-27 11:11:37,249 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.checkpoint.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,249 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.dns.interface is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.dns.interface
2013-11-27 11:11:37,249 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.speculative.execution.slowNodeThreshold is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.speculative.slownodethreshold
2013-11-27 11:11:37,250 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.sort.factor is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.io.sort.factor
2013-11-27 11:11:37,250 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.https.need.client.auth is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client.https.need-auth
2013-11-27 11:11:37,250 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.checkpoint.edits.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.edits.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,250 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.hours is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.hours
2013-11-27 11:11:37,250 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jvm.numtasks
2013-11-27 11:11:37,250 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - topology.node.switch.mapping.impl is deprecated. Instead, use net.topology.node.switch.mapping.impl
2013-11-27 11:11:37,254 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.cache.levels is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.taskcache.levels
2013-11-27 11:11:37,254 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.instrumentation is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.instrumentation
2013-11-27 11:11:37,255 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.access.time.precision is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.accesstime.precision
2013-11-27 11:11:37,255 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.queue.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.queuename
2013-11-27 11:11:37,255 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.reduce.child.log.level is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.log.level
2013-11-27 11:11:37,255 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.balance.bandwidthPerSec is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.balance.bandwidthPerSec
2013-11-27 11:11:37,255 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.persist.jobstatus.active is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.active
2013-11-27 11:11:37,255 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.map.output.compression.codec is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec
2013-11-27 11:11:37,255 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.tracker.http.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.http.address
2013-11-27 11:11:37,256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapreduce.jobtracker.split.metainfo.maxsize is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize
2013-11-27 11:11:37,256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.profile.reduces is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.profile.reduces
2013-11-27 11:11:37,256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.inmem.merge.threshold is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.merge.inmem.threshold
2013-11-27 11:11:37,256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.safemode.extension is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.safemode.extension
2013-11-27 11:11:37,256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.checkpoint.period is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period
2013-11-27 11:11:37,256 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
2013-11-27 11:11:37,257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.data.dir is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.datanode.data.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.local.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.cluster.local.dir
2013-11-27 11:11:37,257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - job.end.retry.interval is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.end-notification.retry.interval
2013-11-27 11:11:37,257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.output.compression.type is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type
2013-11-27 11:11:37,257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - io.sort.spill.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent
2013-11-27 11:11:37,257 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.permissions.supergroup is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.permissions.superusergroup
2013-11-27 11:11:37,258 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.markreset.buffer.percent
2013-11-27 11:11:37,258 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - tasktracker.http.threads is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.http.threads
2013-11-27 11:11:37,258 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.compress.map.output is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.compress
2013-11-27 11:11:37,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.reduce.input.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.input.buffer.percent
2013-11-27 11:11:37,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.tasks.sleeptime-before-sigkill is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.tasks.sleeptimebeforesigkill
2013-11-27 11:11:37,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.tasktracker.dns.nameserver is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.dns.nameserver
2013-11-27 11:11:37,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.shuffle.read.timeout is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.read.timeout
2013-11-27 11:11:37,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.max.tracker.blacklists is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.tasktracker.maxblacklists
2013-11-27 11:11:37,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - topology.script.number.args is deprecated. Instead, use net.topology.script.number.args
2013-11-27 11:11:37,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.shuffle.input.buffer.percent
2013-11-27 11:11:37,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.merge.recordsBeforeProgress is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.merge.progress.records
2013-11-27 11:11:37,262 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - dfs.write.packet.size is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.client-write-packet-size
2013-11-27 11:11:37,262 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.jobtracker.restart.recover is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.restart.recover
2013-11-27 11:11:37,262 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.map.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.speculative
2013-11-27 11:11:37,262 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.job.tracker.jobhistory.lru.cache.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.jobhistory.lru.cache.size
2013-11-27 11:11:37,262 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.map.child.log.level is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.log.level
2013-11-27 11:11:37,262 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.tracker.report.address is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.tasktracker.report.address
2013-11-27 11:11:37,262 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.speculative.execution.speculativeCap is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.speculative.speculativecap
2013-11-27 11:11:37,263 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.skip.maxrecords
2013-11-27 11:11:37,263 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.task.profile.maps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.task.profile.maps
2013-11-27 11:11:37,263 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - mapred.jobtracker.instrumentation is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.instrumentation
```

But when I do `DUMP records`.

```
Backend error message during job submission
-------------------------------------------
Unexpected System Error Occured: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.setupUdfEnvAndStores(PigOutputFormat.java:225)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(PigOutputFormat.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1268)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1265)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.ControlledJob.submit(ControlledJob.java:335)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.jobcontrol.JobControl.run(JobControl.java:240)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop20.PigJobControl.run(PigJobControl.java:121)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher$1.run(MapReduceLauncher.java:270)

Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias records

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias records
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:880)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:774)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:372)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:872)
    ... 12 more
================================================================================
```

Content of /temp/temp.txt file is:

```
1950    0       1
1950    22      1
1950    -11     1
1950    111     1
```

What could be wrong ? When I issue `pig` command I don't see any error, there is one warning saying couldn't load native library from platform.

Thanks!

Comment: which distribution? Did you compile pig 0.12 yourself?

Comment: Pig 0.12 from [here](http://mirror.metrocast.net/apache/pig/pig-0.12.0/) and Apache Hadoop from [here](http://www.trieuvan.com/apache/hadoop/common/stable2/).

No, I did not compile pig myself, do I need to do that?

Comment: you'll need to make sure pig is compiled with the same version Hadoop you're trying to use. HDP 2.0 ships with Pig 0.12.

Comment: Your question contains insufficient info to be sure, but the first error is about a class change. Try to load without schema, and then cast to see what happens. If you were distracted by the final error, check [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias Generic Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution)